# Why does Array.filter's predicate have a return type of unknown (rather than boolean)?

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, types, ecmascript-5

In the TypeScript core libraries, [`Array.filter`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/303ed3a357b3e834d70e1e578c3a194b33813377/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1171-L1182) has two signatures:

```
filter<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];

filter(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];
```

I understand the first signature - it lets a type assertion predicate narrow the type of the array.

However, the second signature seems like it make the predicate return `boolean` instead of `unknown`. I understand that JS is more permissive than this and will coerce the value into a `boolean`, but TypeScript doesn't seem to usually encourage implicit conversions.

Changing it to `boolean` would seem to prevent more bugs, ie:

```
// Because the return type is unknown, TS silently accepts this unintentional number | boolean return type
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(el => someMap.get(el) ?? 0 > 1) // equivalent to someMap.get(el) ?? (0 > 1)
```

What is the justification behind this signature?

The same question applies to `some` and `any`, but not to [`find`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/303ed3a357b3e834d70e1e578c3a194b33813377/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1793).

Comment: Just a guess: they tried making it `boolean` and it produced type errors on too much existing legitimate code, so they reluctantly changed it. Aka a compromise.

Comment: Looks like it was originally `boolean` and people complained that it broke their truthy/falsy callbacks, see [microsoft/typescript#5850](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5850)

Comment: why do they have `unknown` and `any` mixed up  in `predicate` return type?

Comment: and for non generic arrays such as `Uint8Array`, it still uses `boolean`:  `find(predicate: (value: number, index: number, obj: Uint8Array) => boolean, thisArg?: any): number | undefined;` why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` predicate [is only required to return a boolean-ish value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters). Since *any* value can be coerced to boolean in JS, this means it could be any type: it is literally `unknown` to us. Specifying a return of `boolean` would be too narrow: valid predicates would not compile.

Consider a filter to accept all non-empty string elements:

```
let input: (string|undefined|null)[] = ["yeah", "", "okay", undefined, null];
let nonEmptyStrings = input.filter(x => x);
```

This "clean up" predicate is a pretty reasonable kind of filter you shouldn't be surprised to find in the wild. It is JS "slang" for more verbose, uptight phrasings, like ...

```
input.filter(x => x !=== null && x.length > 0)
input.filter(x => Boolean(x))
input.filter(x => !!x);
```

(Personally, I consider the first line above an improvement, because it makes the intent clear. No one will be unsure whether empty strings are meant to be filtered out.)

But in other situations it's less clear whether verbosity helps, such as when checking for the existence of a property. Compare these two...

```
input.filter(x => x.someOptionalProperty) // not type safe, nice to read
input.filter(x => Object.hasOwnProperty('someOptionalProperty')) // type safe, yucky
```

Dunno about you, but I *vastly* prefer the former. It's shorter, idiomatic, and you can IDE context ("go to definition").

But more important than whether non-boolean returns are "good style" or not, one of TS's goals is to provide a structured typing of *all valid JS*, and not to wish away the dust and cobwebs. It is not contentious that filter predicates can validly return *any value*, so the result really must be `unknown`.

(Maybe one day TS will support a `booleanish` sugar type; like `unknown` but expected to be interpreted as boolean? That might make the signature's motivation clearer.)

Comment: I wrote this answer in a way that makes it sound like I was never confused by the factory `filter` predicate. But I absolutely was. (I found this question cos I was practically googling the title!)